# Overcoming problems with imbalanced classes in Random Forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I want to create a random forest classification based on a dataset with imbalanced classes.

Now I want to calculate the PPV of each random forest classification based on all triple combinations of features (and thereby find the „best“ marker combination, which is here defined as the one with the highest PPV and BACC). This is the code I’m using.

```
# 1) My testset
set.seed(5)

data <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100,10,5),B=rnorm(100,15,2),C=rnorm(100,20,5),
                           D=rnorm(100,3,1.5),E=rnorm(100,12,10),G=rnorm(100,12,10),
                           Class=c(rep("A",90), rep("B", 10)))
data[,"Class"] <- as.factor(data[,"Class"])
```

My first suggestion would be that the data are not well separable, because the values of the features of both groups ("A" and "B") are from the same distribution.

```
# 2) Create vector contain all combinations of 3 features (without the class)
allcombis <- combn(colnames(data)[-7], m = 3) #exclude column 5, the class column
dfpar <- apply(allcombis, 2, function(i) paste(i, collapse=" + ")) 

# 3) The output should be a dataframe containing all feature combinations and the PPV
dffinal <- data.frame(par= as.character(dfpar), TP=0, FP=0, TN=0, FN=0, PPV=0, BACC=0)

# 4) Create trainings and validation set
rows <- sample(rownames(data), replace = TRUE, size = length(rownames(data))*0.7)
train <- data[as.numeric(rows),]
validation <- data[-as.numeric(names(table(rows))),]


for (i in dfpar){
  # Create random forest model
  library(randomForest)
  fit <- randomForest(as.formula(paste("Class", i, sep=" ~ ")),
                      data=train, 
                      importance=TRUE, 
                      ntree=1000)    
  # Apply random forest on validation dataset
  Prediction <- predict(fit, validation)
  confmatrix <- table(validation[,"Class"], Prediction)

  # Calculate variable of interest: PPV
  confmatrix_results <- confusionMatrix(confmatrix)
  dffinal[which(dffinal[,"par"]==i), "TP"] <- signif(as.vector(confmatrix_results[["table"]][1,1]), digits = 6)
  dffinal[which(dffinal[,"par"]==i), "FP"] <- signif(as.vector(confmatrix_results[["table"]][1,2]), digits = 6)
  dffinal[which(dffinal[,"par"]==i), "FN"] <- signif(as.vector(confmatrix_results[["table"]][2,1]), digits = 6)
  dffinal[which(dffinal[,"par"]==i), "TN"] <- signif(as.vector(confmatrix_results[["table"]][2,2]), digits = 6)
  dffinal[which(dffinal[,"par"]==i), "PPV"] <- signif(as.vector(confmatrix_results[[4]]["Pos Pred Value"]), digits = 6)
  dffinal[which(dffinal[,"par"]==i), "BACC"] <- signif(as.vector(confmatrix_results[[4]]["Balanced Accuracy"]), digits = 6)
}

View(dffinal)
```

But as a result, one marker combination has a BACC of 95% and a PPV of 1. After some reading I came across this blog: 
http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

Here oversampling of the underrepresented group was suggested.

```
#######
# Exchange 4) with this: Create new trainings and new validation set
## I have a 9:1 ratio of classes in my dataset. Therefore I oversample the underrepresented group "B"

validatonrowsA <- sample(rownames(split(data, data[,"Class"])$A), replace = FALSE, size = length(rownames(data))*0.2)
validatonrowsB <- sample(rownames(split(data, data[,"Class"])$B), replace = TRUE, size = length(rownames(data))*0.2)

trainrowsA <- which(!(rownames(split(data, data[,"Class"])$A) %in% names(table(trainrowsA))), useNames = TRUE)
trainrowsB <- sample(rownames(split(data, data[,"Class"])$B), replace = TRUE, size = length(rownames(data))*0.8)

train <- data[c(trainrowsA, trainrowsB),]
validation <- data[c(validatonrowsA, validatonrowsB),]
```

But now the classification is nearly perfect? What is wrong with the code?  I read the documentation of the [randomForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package, but I found no answer.   Thank you in advance for suggestions!